# How do I point to the the identifier of my most recent RDS DB snapshot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rds

I am trying to use the Boto3 restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot() method in a Lambda function. One of the needed parameters is the snapshot identifier that I want to restore from. I would like to avoid manually entering the identifier each time, and instead point to the most recent snapshot identifier. How would I go about doing this?

I'm using Python 3.7 btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call [`describe_db_snapshots()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_db_snapshots) to retrieve a list of snapshots.

You can supply a `DBInstanceIdentifier` to request a list of snapshots related to a specific database.

The response will be a Python *list* of `DBSnapshots`. You can use Python to sort the list by `SnapshotCreateTime` and then retrieve the `DBSnapshotIdentifier` for the most recent snapshot.

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing this. I've called describe_db_snapshots() with the proper DBInstanceIdentifier, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: You can `print()` the response and see what it provides.

Comment: 'x = response['DBSnapshots'] #x holds all snapshot objects
 y = x[0] #y is a snapshot object
print(y['DBSnapshotIdentifier'])' So far I can successfully print the DBSnapshotIdentifier from one of my objects. The last thing I have to figure out is how to sort by SnapshotCreateTime.

Comment: Do you know why this line of code doesn't work? x.sort(key=lambda x: x.SnapshotCreateTime reverse=True)

Comment: Try: `x.sort(key=lambda x: x['SnapshotCreateTime'] reverse=True)`

Comment: I was getting a syntax error with that but I managed to figure it out. I had to create a function and use it as the key instead of lambda.

Comment: Oops, it's missing a comma: `x.sort(key=lambda x: x['SnapshotCreateTime'], reverse=True)`